Wrong type is generated by typescript
Here is my ts code
declare function get_el(): number | null;
var el=get_el() 
export const im=function(){
  if (el==null){
    const ans= {
      exists:false
    }
    return ans
  }
  const ans2={
    value:7,    
    exists:true,

  }    
  return ans2
}()

By looking at the code, the type of im should be:
const im: {
    value: number;
    exists: boolean;
} | {
    exists: boolean;
}

But in reality it is not. the generated .d.ts reads:
export declare const im: {
    exists: boolean;
};

my question is: why is it?

many time typescript pick wrong type if type is not defined. To avoid this problem you should use interface or type to declare the type

Can you report this on TypeScript's repo? I created a repro for you.

@fregante it is a bug in ts? here is the github report: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/60043

TypeScript playground also inferred it that way. I guess part of the reason is because { value: number; exists: boolean; } is assignable to { exists: boolean;}  ?

Although computed type for object literal and variable are the same { exists: boolean; }, object flags are different. Anonymous, ObjectLiteral, FreshLiteral, ContainsObjectOrArrayLiteral, ObjectTypeKindMask, RequiresWidening, PropagatingFlags in case of ObjectLiteralExpression and Anonymous, ObjectTypeKindMask in case of Identifier

TS uses heuristics to infer types. Subtype reduction sometimes happens when TS picks a best common type. Different code can result in different inference, as shown in this playground link. The inference algorithm works well over a wide range of real-world code, but it can't always do what the developer wants. If you really care about the type, use annotations instead of relying on inference. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

This... is a weird one.
Changing your declaration of im to
const im = function() {
  if (el === null) {
    return {
      exists: false
    }
  }
  const ans2 = {
    value: 7,    
    exists: true,
  }   
  return ans2; 
}()

the resulting type becomes
 const im: {
    value: number;
    exists: boolean;
} | {
    exists: boolean;
}

If you further shorten it with for example
const im = function() {
  return el === null ? {
      exists: false
    } : {
    value: 7,    
    exists: true,
  } 
}()

the resulting type becomes
const im: {
    exists: boolean;
    value?: undefined;
} | {
    value: number;
    exists: boolean;
}

Even changing the declaration of el to
function get_el(): number | null {
    return Math.random() < 1 ? 1 : null;
}

const el = get_el();

so that Typescript couldn't infer anything wrong, doesn't change anything.
In the github issue created by OP it is mentioned that this is due to subtype reduction, but it feels weird that making small changes like this results in an entirely different type.
To make sure the returned type is correct, you can always explicitly set the type:
const im = function(): {
    exists: boolean;
} | {
    value: number;
    exists: boolean;
} {
  return el === null ? {
      exists: false
    } : {
    value: 7,    
    exists: true,
  } 
}()

